# Generate Near Table and keep all attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to calculate the angle and distance of points to surrounding polygons. The table is good and what I need but it doesn't maintain all records; the unique point and polygon IDs are not there. Is there a way to maintain those? I will need them for further calculations.

I'm using the "Generate Near Table" tool in ArcGIS 10. There are complete columns missing. I have a specific ID number assigned to each record and that column amongst others that I don't care about as much, didn't come with. The rows seem all there, I think, but not all columns. I can't join the near table with any data layer either to get that column back.

Comment: Some clarification would help. What software are you using? Which specific tool or technique are you using to calculate nearest neighbor? Are there entire records (rows) missing, or is each record missing values for particular attributes (columns)?

Comment: I'm using the "generate near table" tool in ArcGIS 10. There are complete columns missing. I have specific ID # assigned to each record and that column amongst others that I don't care about as much, didn't come with. The rows seem all there, I think, but not all columns. I can't join the near table with any data layer either to get that column back.

Answer (score 2):

Because near tables can be absolutely *massive*, they only contain the bare minimum amount of information. You have to join them back to the input data using either `IN_FID` or `NEAR_FID`, which correspond to the `OBJECTID` field (or `OID`, `FID`, or whatever the automatic unique ID field is for your feature class) of the Input Features and Near Features, respectively. See the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000) for more info.

Once you've joined the near table to the features using the appropriate field, you can export the data to permanently attach the Near Table data to the features.

(Bear in mind that, unless you used the "Find only closest feature" option, your Near Table will almost certainly contain multiple matches for a given Input or Near Feature.)