# Finding nearest street name from selected point using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, proximity

There are two data layers with house numbers and street. My house numbers are point type, and my street layer with road names is line type. What I want to do in my project is to find  15 meters near the street and its name when I choose any of these door numbers.

For example, I click a point and run this code. Then it makes a table with streets 15 meters away from this point. However, it does not tell me which street is on that table. I need street names in that table. In other words, in this table and in this study, I want to learn the street names to which the point is close according to the distance given.

How can I do that?

Comment: This could help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21860/generate-near-table-and-keep-all-attributes

Comment: I tried this before but i still can't show the column with street names in the new table. So I don't understand which streets are close to the point. @TimothyDalton

Comment: Can you share the code where you are trying to join back to the origina ldata?

Comment: I changed the question I asked above, added some photos and code. If you can look over there and help me accordingly, I would be glad. @TimothyDalton

Comment: @ÖzgeA your table **near_parks_trails_deneme** has the id of the streets within 15m. You can use the Join Table to retrieve the street name?

Comment: Without any script, your question may be closed to anwsers after a while.

Answer (score 6):

Add a field named `YOL_NAME` to `Kapi` layer, select a feature, then run the following script. (First, backup `Kapi` and `Yol` layer data sources)

```
yol_layer = "Yol"
yol_name_field = "AD" # yol name field in yol layer

kapi_layer = "Kapi"
kapi_yol_field = "YOL_NAME" # newly added yol name field in kapi layer to be populated

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(kapi_layer, ["SHAPE@", kapi_yol_field]) as cursor:
    for kapi in cursor:
        yol_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(yol_layer, ["SHAPE@", yol_name_field])
        # distance dictionary {"AD": distane, "AD": distance, ...}
        ds = {yol[1]: kapi[0].distanceTo(yol[0]) for yol in yol_cursor}
        k = min(ds, key=ds.get) # get the key ("AD") with minimum value
        d = ds[k]               # get the minimum value

        # set "YOL_NAME" based on min value is less than 5 or not
        kapi[1] = k if d <= 5 else ''

        cursor.updateRow(kapi)
        print("Yol Name: " + k)
    
    del yol_cursor
```

**Notes:**

- If there is no road in 5 m, it writes empty string to `YOL_NAME`.
- If there are multiple roads within 5 m, then it gets the minimum one.
- When you have a selection, a `cursor` will use only the selected ones. That means if you select nothing, the script will use all point features.

Example:

[image]

---

To print all road names within 5m use this script:

```
...
distance = 5

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(kapi_layer, ["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:

    for kapi in cursor:
        yol_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(yol_layer, ["SHAPE@", yol_name_field])

        # distance dictionary {"AD": distane, "AD": distance, ...}
        ds = {yol[1]: kapi[0].distanceTo(yol[0]) for yol in yol_cursor}

        names = [ds[i] for i in ds if ds[i] <= distance]
        print(names)

    del yol_cursor
```

Comment: Will i run this code with the previous code I wrote? And also i have an error:

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
RuntimeError: Objects in this class cannot be updated outside of the edit session [Kapi]

Comment: No. just change layers and fields names, select any point and run. Using a tool in toolbox slows you down. Cursors are fast.

Comment: i have an error: Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 8, in <module> RuntimeError: Objects in this class cannot be updated outside of the edit session [Kapi]

Comment: Start editing session for Kapi layer, then try again. I am on Ubuntu now, I cannot check.

Comment: I get an error on the with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor line, I wonder if it could be a problem in terms of syntax.